# Angular: child route is not updated correctly

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing

I have a UserComponent (route user/:userId) with a button.
When the button is clicked, the route changes to user/123/hobby/456 which triggers a HobbyComponent. This component has a pagination with "next" and "previous" buttons. When one of the buttons is clicked, I need to do the following:

1. Change the route to the new hobbyId (from user/123/hobby/**456** to user/123/hobby/**789**)
2. Update the data on the HobbyComponent to display the requested hobby

When the button on the UserComponent is clicked, the route works correctly and the HobbyComponent is displayed with no problem. I have an issue with **updating** the child route.
If I add this.route.navigate function into the HobbyComponent to update the child route, the route changes incorrectly: it doesn't replace the hobbyId in the route, instead, it appends a new one -> user/123/hobby/**456**/**789** and the app breaks after that because this route doesn't exist.
How to fix that? I want to avoid passing a route change event into the UserComponent, because the components don't have parent-child relationships so I don't see an easy way to pass the event.

Routes:

```
export const UserRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: 'user/:userId', component: UserComponent, children: [
       { path: 'hobby/:hobbyId', component: HobbyComponent},
   ]}
]
```

UserComponent:

```
// button click event
openHobby() {
  this.router.navigate([this.hobbyId], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
}
```

HobbyComponent:

```
navigateToNextHobby(nextHobbyId) {
   this.router.navigate([nextHobbyId], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
}
```

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['..', nextHobbyId], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});`

Comment: Or `this.router.navigate(['../' + nextHobbyId], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});`

Comment: @Benny I think `..` or `../` is only for template relative routing. This is being achieved by `{relativeTo: this.activatedRoute}` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a simple Stackblitz project [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sibling-routes?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts) that demonstrates a similar scenario. Notice that you can navigate from one hobby to another sibling hobby under the same user.

**My routes are:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "user/:userId",
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [{ path: "hobby/:hobbyId", component: HobbyComponent }]
  }
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<button (click)="gotoHobby(1)">Go to hobby 1</button>
```

**Navigation from user to hobby code is:**

```
  async gotoHobby(hobbyId: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.router.navigate(['hobby', hobbyId], { relativeTo: this.route })
  }
```

**Navigation from hobby to hobby:**

**HTML:**

```
<button *ngIf="hobbyId === '1'" (click)="gotoHobby(2)">Go to hobby 2</button>
<button *ngIf="hobbyId === '2'" (click)="gotoHobby(1)">Go to hobby 1</button>
```

**code:**

```
  async gotoHobby(hobbyId: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.router.navigate(["hobby", hobbyId], {
      relativeTo: this.route.parent
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hey Benny, thank you for your reply and spending time on the issue! I need to navigate from one hobby to another by clicking a button which is inside a hobby component. In your case the route change is triggered from the user component and as I said in my question, that wasn't a problem. Do you know how I can change the route being inside the hobbyComponent? Because the navigation code you provided won't work

Comment: I updated my answer and my project - added navigation from hobby to hobby. Please take a look

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative routing based on the *main* route instead of the *activated* route:

```
navigateToNextHobby(nextHobbyId) {
    this.router.navigate([nextHobbyId], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

So it is relative to the **user** route.

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure what this.route should be. I tried to do do this:

navigateToNextHobby(nextHobbyId) {
    this.router.navigate([nextHobbyId], {relativeTo: this.router.url});
}

however, i get an error "type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ActivatedRoute'"